# New to sound design, how do I recreate Shining - Black Jazz drum tone using plugins?

Tags: plugins, drum

I'm new to sound design and recording, having been a bedroom guitarist for many years now. I'd like to recreate a drum tone like the following band Shining - Black Jazz:

https://shining.bandcamp.com/album/blackjazz

What drum plugin would come close to this? Is it possible to create it using stock logic drum plugins but adjust the EQ and reverb?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd get a lot of joy out of Addictive Drums 2, particularly the Metal and Black Velvet (for the bigger snares that even have a "gatey" reverb) kits. They (and this is true for all of AD2) have a great tone out-of-the-box, all premixed and ready to go, and you can tweak them further. This saves a lot of time dialing things in.

From the example you linked, I hear similarities in punch and overall aggressive drive. Of course, then you'll need to play it in action — but there are also example MIDI patterns provided that you can fine-tune to taste.

https://www.xlnaudio.com/products/addictive_drums_2/adpak/metal

https://www.xlnaudio.com/products/addictive_drums_2/adpak/black_velvet

Comment: Thanks! Can I also recreate a Deftones - white pony drum tone with addictive drums and a room reverb blugin?